# Scheduling a monthly Job for .net code

Tags: c#, .net, job-scheduling

I currently have a web application, that has certain filters and on those filters a method from a class library is called and the respective activities are performed like processing records, placing files on certain locations on different servers.
I want to automate this process.
How can I achieve this and what is the best possible way?
I read about various options windows service, Cache Item Call backs, Workflows.
But not able to evaluate.

Please help me.

Comment: There are several ways to schedule jobs. You can have a program run using the Task Scheduler with a console application, a windows service that runs in the background, a wcf service that waits for requests, a workflow application, or several other approaches.

Comment: Scheduling a job isn't really a question for the application or programming language, it's a question for the host or operating system.  Windows has a built-in task scheduler, Linux has `cron`, both of which can run applications or commands on a specified schedule.  Or you could create background processes (Windows Services or a daemon in Linux) which run continually and can perform some task at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a console application for the process and then schedule it through Windows Scheduler. Or you may look at **[`Quartz.NET - Enterprise Job Scheduler for .NET Platform`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)**

Comment: Thanks. I tried with Quartz .net . I could schedule my tasks and I deployed it as a Service using Windows Services. Works Great!! Exactly what i wanted. Thanks